# How do I get average number of logins for each hour of each day from a single column of data (logins in datetime format) in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a single column of datetime data (table name is login). I want to work out the average number of logins for each hour of each dayname (i.e., Monday, Tuesday, etc).

I tried the following:

```
select d, h, avg(logincount)

from
(
    select dayname(login) d, hour(login) h, count(*) as logincount
    from login
    group by d, h
) dt

group by d, h
```

This gives me the total number of logins, but I want the average.

Comment: Well yeah. Your subquery produces a single row for each hour of each day. An average will be the same as the count if the denominator of the avg is 1.

Comment: @dfundako Thank you. I see what you mean. How do you advise I write the query?

Comment: if you remove grouping by hour in the outer query, you will get the average hourly login rate by day, i think.

Comment: What you want? for example for day 1 there are 20 login in hour 1 and 10 login in hour 2 (same other counts for other hours 3 to 24). Do you need the Average for day 1 = 15 (considering only hour 1 and 2 value)? Also please mention appropriate database name.

Comment: It might help to look at the inner query only, then you'll know what kind of data you're working with for the outer query/grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you the average over all hours of a day:

```
select dayname(login) as d, hour(login) as h,
       count(*) / count(distinct date(login)) as hourly_average
from login
group by d, h
```

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. What I meant by the average for each hour for each day, was the average for each hour for each dayname, so that I could ask, for example, what are the average number of logins on a Monday at 8-9am?

Comment: @Mark . . . I adjusted the answer.

Comment: I inserted a comma before count(*) and then that works perfectly. Thanks.